# Function has inconsistent return points

Tags: javascript, jquery

When running Intellij's inspections on some javascript I wrote, it reports

> function 'createPages' has inconsistent return points at line 35

But I'm not sure what it means, or how to solve this issue.

The function looks like this:

```
function createPages(noOfCounts) {
    var default_page = 1, default_count = 15;
    if (noOfCounts != "" && noOfCounts != null) {
        if (noOfCounts > default_count) {
            try {
                var tempVal = parseInt(noOfCounts / default_count);
                jQuery("#page").val(tempVal);
                return true;
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert('Error . ' + e);
            }
        } else {
            alert("It should not be less than the 15 and should be a number");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        jQuery("#page").val(default_page);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And is being called like so:

```
var valid = createPages(noOfCounts);
```

Comment: When quoting an error with a line number and the code associated, it would probably be useful to indicate which line is the line in the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your function will (in effect) return `undefined` implicitly after it reaches `alert('Error . ' + e);`, because execution will reach the end of the function without an explicit `return`.

So probably making sure that all code paths through the function return a value explicitly will get rid of the IntelliJ error.