# What does it mean to have inconsistent return points in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

Here's a little javascript code in NodeJs that I'm using to save uploaded files. I'm trying to convert it to Typescript. It throws an error on the word save - "Function save has inconsistent return points".

```
public save(req, res, next) {
        // validate if upload was successful
        if (!req.files || !req.files.userfile) return next(new Error('Upload data not received, can\'t proceed.'));
        var userfile = req.files.userfile;
        // examine this object for available attributes
        console.log(userfile);
        // ensure public/data dir exists
        var dataDir = 'public/data';

        //Add temporarily unique name here
        var filenum = 0;
        while(fs.existsSync(dataDir + "/" + tempFile(filenum))){
            filenum++;
        }
        var target = path.join(dataDir, tempFile(filenum));
        fs.rename(userfile.path, target, function (err) {
            req.uploadLink = target.replace(/public/gi, '');
            next(err);
            // cleanup
            fs.unlink(userfile.path, function () {});
        });
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714477/function-has-inconsistent-return-points

Comment: TypeScript doesn't issue this error - what other tools are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any tools other than the IDE - which is Webstorm. I have NodeJS and Express installed.

Comment: I added a "return false" statement to the end of the code which made the error go away. There's a lot of other bugs in my code, because of which my code is not running right now and I'm not able to check the implications of adding this.

Comment: WebStorm is written by JetBrains - who also created ReSharper. I imagine the same feature is in both.

Answer (score 2):

Ryan is right - TypeScript will check for incompatible return types and warn you with the `Could not find the best common type...` error if your function returns, for example, a string in one place and a number in a different place.

If your function falls-through, it will pick the type from the return statements, so if you return a string within a condition and then fall-through later, the TypeScript compiler will infer the return type to be `string`.

I tested this in the TypeScript Playground with many variations - so this means the warning in Visual Studio is coming from another extension - looking at likely candidates on my set-up makes me think you have ReSharper running (or perhaps you are using a different IDE that also checks this).

ReSharper has checked for `inconsistent return points` since version 6.1 and they did introduce general TypeScript support in version 8.1.

The fix is to return a common type from all return statements, which in your case would be to remove the `return` keyword altogether if your calling code doesn't rely on the result of that call.

Comment: TypeScript does not perform this kind of analysis; there's something else doing this.